# Finding an element with jquery with wild card characters

Tags: jquery

I have a scenario, where i need to find an element using a particular string

```
("id^='16'")
```

And my requirement is it should only fetch values with id= '16k','16M' and not values like '16KK' or '16MK'

i.e. it should only fetch for id's which has only one character after search string

Answer (score 2):

use `filter` on returned elements .

```
$("id^='16'").filter(
function() {
        return this.id.match(/16[a-zA-Z]/);
    });
```

Comment: ok we basically had the same idea. but yours probably performs better than mine.

Comment: @Alp, yes since it works on a subset instead of all DOM elements .

Comment: will it work if there are are 0 or 1 characters(may be special characters) but not more than 1 character ?

Comment: You just have to change the regex in the filter function, it will work for anything you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Use the jquery attribute selector with the filter:

```
//jQuery requires brackets for Attribute Selector
$("[id^='16']").filter(
function() {
    //Match if not followed by another character
    return this.id.match(/16[a-zA-Z](?![a-zA-Z])/g);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jQuery custom filter:

```
$(document).filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr("id").match( /16[a-z]/i ); 
});
```